# Why my notification does not work in android TV emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tv

I am trying to implement an android TV application by using android studio and TV emulator.

I call the following code blocks at the onCreate function of the main activity. It is running for android mobile devices but not working on the Android TV emulator.

```
String channel_name = "myChannel";
String channel_description = "mySChannel";
String CHANNEL_ID = "idididf";
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line..."))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = channel_name;
    String description = channel_description;
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

notificationManager.notify(12312, builder.build()); // 0 is the request code, it should be unique id
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With very few exceptions, notifications are not shown on Android TV.

Comment: but i need to show my application's notifications on the TV screen